# Do TinyMCE advtemplate items need a unique title

Tags: tinymce

I'm just looking for a straight answer from somewhere but can't seem to find it in the docs.

I'm using the advtemplate plugin, and seem to get an error whenever an item has the same name as another item in the list.

Is there a way to have a non-user editable template list (using the `advtemplate_templates` option) that may or may not have repeating titles in different categories?